# provide simple method to get current speed (implementing speedometer)

Tags: swift, core-location

Could you please give me example how to calculate current "speed", I'm working on my first simple app ala speedometer?

I figure out to use `didUpdateToLocation`

also I found that I need to use formula `speed = distance / duration`

Is it right? how to calculate duration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic steps that you need to go through look something like this:

1. Create a CLLocationmanager instance
2. Assign a delegate with the
   appropriate callback method
3. Check to see if the "speed" is set on the CLLocation in the callback, if it is - there's your speed
4. (Optionally) if the "speed" isn't
   set, try calculating it from the distance between the last update
   and the current, divided by the difference in timestamps

   ```
   import CoreLocation

   class locationDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
       var last:CLLocation?
       override init() {
         super.init()
       }
       func processLocation(_ current:CLLocation) {
           guard last != nil else {
               last = current
               return
           }
           var speed = current.speed
           if (speed > 0) {
               print(speed) // or whatever
           } else {
               speed = last!.distance(from: current) / (current.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(last!.timestamp))
               print(speed)
           }
           last = current
       }
       func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                    didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
           for location in locations {
               processLocation(location)
           }
       }
   }

   var del = locationDelegate()
   var lm = CLLocationManager();
   lm.delegate = del
   lm.startUpdatingLocation()
   ```

Comment: Man, what is *up* with the Stack Overflow editor today? That took way too many edits to get the formatting correct.

Comment: I've tried to implement similar this. Could you explain diffs betweet just get speed from loaction and calculate it using formula? cause when i print two ways of speed they have slightly different values

Comment: My problem is on real device, when i'm driving, the speed is incorrect. I used `locations.speed` in `didUpdateLocations`.

Comment: The "speed" property of the CLLocation is the instantaneous speed as reported at the instant of the timestamp. This will be different than the average speed since the last update, which is what you get by dividing the distance travelled by the time between updates.

Comment: Also, if the phone is moving in anything other than a straight line, the accuracy of the calculated speed will necessarily be less accurate.

Comment: And finally, be sure to check the "horizontalAccuracy" of the location. Your calculated speed can't be any more accurate than the uncertainty in the positions, obviously. If the accuracy is +-60m, and you've "moved" anything between 0-120m, you might actually still be in the same place.

Comment: So Did I understand clearly that it would be better to use speed property of location instance? Could you give me example how to manage with horizontal accuracy? 
cause I set the desiredAccuracy as kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

Comment: Yes, if you get "speed" values, use those. In cases where Location Services can't provide speed data (e.g. bad GPS signal), you can try to calculate it from the displacement and time interval, as shown. That's going to give you possibly-terrible results for any two data points, but over time, you can filter that to get better results.

Comment: Speed is part of Location object. Unit is m/s so if you need km/h you have to multiply by 3.6.
Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation